Accessing method values within the same class
Essentially, I am trying to access the value of one function and I'm trying to use it within another function.
This is the current function I have:
 def getMove(self):
        print("Coordinates must range from 0 to 2, 0 corresponding to the first row/column, onwards")
        xcoor = int(input("What is your x coordinate?"))
        ycoor = int(input("What is your y coordinate?"))
        
        if xcoor and ycoor not in range(0,3):
            print("Coordinates must be between 0 and 2")


        return f"({xcoor},{ycoor})"


and I am trying to use the 'xcoor' and y'coor' variables here to set the move with the marker wherever the user specified. I thought that since you can access a 2d array's individual element and it assign it a value, you could do the same thing when using variables, but this does not appear to be the case. Maybe I don't understand how classes work when it comes to access or its syntactical issue, either way, some guidance and/or further reading would be appreciated.
def makeMove(board,marker):
        #todo: code to alternate between players
    
        marker = "X"
        #makesmove
        board[xcoor][ycoor] == marker

Full code if needed:

class Tictactoe:

    def __init__(self,playerone,playertwo):
        self.playerone = playerone
        self.playertwo = playertwo
        
        
        
        

    def newBoard(self):
        # creates new board
        return [[None, None, None],
                 [None, None, None],
                 [None, None, None]
                 ]
        
        
        
        


    def renderBoard(self):
        board = self.newBoard()
        
        # Prints current state of the board
        for row in board:
            print("|", end="")
            for cell in row:
                if cell is None:
                    print("   |", end="")
                else:
                    print(f" {cell} |", end="")
            print("\n" + "-" * 13)



    def getMove(self):
        print("Coordinates must range from 0 to 2, 0 corresponding to the first row/column, onwards")
        xcoor = int(input("What is your x coordinate?"))
        ycoor = int(input("What is your y coordinate?"))
        
        if xcoor and ycoor not in range(0,3):
            print("Coordinates must be between 0 and 2")

        
        return f"({xcoor},{ycoor})"


    def makeMove(board,marker):
        #todo: code to alternate between players
    
        marker = "X"
        #makesmove
        board[xcoor][ycoor] == marker

        


        

    def getWinner(self):
        #todo write win conditions
        '''if player one marks 3 in a row, player one wins, end game
        if player two marks 3 in a row, player 2 wins, end game
        '''
        pass

    def resetButton(self):
        #todo: create a reset button that clears the board.
        pass

    def runGame(self):
        #todo: write code that starts the game.
        pass

    def isBoardFull(self):
        #todo: write code that checks if board is full
        pass


def main():
    test = Tictactoe("playerone", "playertwo")
    print(test.makeMove())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


if xcoor and ycoor not in range(0,3): will not do what you expect - check out How to test multiple variables for equality against a single value?

This question is similar to: What is the purpose of the return statement? How is it different from printing?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To be more specific - return the coordinates from getMove (preferably as a tuple, then call getMove in makeMove.

By the way, check out [mre]. We always appreciate it when you post your code! But please make sure that it's the minimal sample needed to demonstrate your question/reproduce your problem - that makes it much easier for us to identify what you're asking.

== marker also will not do what you expect. Use one equal sign to set values

The newBoard method should set the board, rather than returning it: i.e. self.board = [[None, ... ]]. Also, the renderBoard method should not call newBoard, otherwise it will lose all the move history. Instead, just do for row in self.board. Likewise, the makeMove method should do self.board[xcoor][ycoor] = marker (and its signature should be def makeMove(self, xcoor, ycoor)). The getMove method can then do self.makeMove(xcoor, ycoor). In general, use attributes to save the current state of the game and then access those values via self in the methods.

Methods within classes can call each other. So, if you can change the return type of getMove function, then you can call it inside makeMove to access the coordinates.

Turn this return f"({xcoor},{ycoor})" into return xcoor,ycoor. getMove is now returning a tuple instead of a string.

Inside makeMove call the getMove function to get the coordinates.
#makesmove
coordinates = getMove()
# access the coordinates using indexes
print(f"{coordinates[0]}, {coordinates[1]}")



You can use other return types too, like arrays, but tuple is probably good for your case.

Did you mean self.getMove()?

You can return a tuple from getMove()
    def getMove():
        # your code
        return xcoor,ycoor

and in makeMove(board, marker) call xcoor,ycoor = getMove()
or pass it as an argument when calling makeMove(board, marker, coordinates)
here coordinates can be tuple, list, dictionary that contains values of xcoor, ycoor
Also if want to assign values than instead of board[xcoor][ycoor] == marker,
use board[xcoor][ycoor] = marker
